# Firebase - how to update another user's email?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I see in the docs [how to update your own email once you are logged in](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users#update_a_users_profile), like so:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

user.updateEmail("user@example.com")
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "User email address updated.");
            }
        }
    });
```

What I want, though, is to be logged in as an user and be able to update the email of another user(The logged in user is an admin). With the approach above that's not possible, because you can get only the current user from FirebaseAuth.

Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is currently no administrative API for Firebase Authentication. We're working on adding this to our server SDKs, but there is no definitive timeline for its availability yet.

Comment: Hello @Frank did you get any solution for this

Comment: Yeah, this now exists: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin

Comment: can we use Admin SDK in our app or it is a must to only use it from the server-side otherwise it won't work?

Comment: The Admin SDK is only for use in trusted environments. See for the options in client-side code this answer I just posted: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68494494/gatsby-and-firebase-admin-sdk/68494631#68494631 Note that there are many more recent questions (and answers) covering this same topic already, so I also recommend searching for those.